# How to test if I can chmod a file in PHP?

Tags: php, permissions

You can chmod a file only if you're the owner of the file. So this question is basically: how do I check if the user running the PHP process is the owner of a certain file?

One way is `fileowner($filename) === posix_getuid()`. However, I'd like to avoid POSIX functions if possible, since it's not supported on all platforms.

What's the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

`fileowner($file) === getmyuid()`

[getmyuid documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmyuid.php)

Comment: My understanding is that getmyuid() is equivalent to `fileowner(__FILE__)`, which isn't the user owning the PHP process.

Comment: You are correct, my misunderstanding, there is no way to do this cross-platform unfortunately. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @LeoJiang @Rafael how about `stat($file)[5]==getmygid()`